# Why does this code is correct (compiler doesn't complaint about it)

Tags: java

I show written by me example, it is caused by the fact that I don't understand some thing in java puzzlers:

```
public class A {

    public A foo() {return new A();}

}

package library;

public class C extends A {
    static  class X extends A {}

    @Override
    public A foo(){
        return new X();
    }
}

package library;

public class B extends A {
    public static class Y extends A { }

    @Override
    public A foo(){
        return new Y();
    }

}

package client;

import library.A;
import library.B;
import library.C;

class Client {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        A b = new B();
        A c = new C();

        A bb = b.foo();
        A cc = c.foo();

        cc.hashCode(); // for me, it should causes compile error

    }
}
```

As you can see, `foo` method is public.

`A cc = c.foo();` - `cc` is instance of non-public type  `X`
`A bb = b.foo();` - `bb` is instance of public type  `Y`

So, when we invoke `cc.hashCode()` we **invoke public method from non-public type which comes from different package**. Why does it is correct?

**Why I think so** ?

In java puzzlers book I found:

> You cannot legally access a member of nonpublic type from another
>   package.

Moreover,

> You can avoid this whole category of problem if you use reflection
>   only for instantiation and use interfaces to invoke methods from the
>   class that implements them and provides a high level of type-safety.

Can anyone explain it ? What does it mean in human-language?

Comment: Why do you say that `C` is a private method? It is very obviously not a *method*, and obviously not *private*: **`public class C`**. It is **public**, not private, and it is a **class**, not a method.

Comment: I make many typos, I corrent it in a while.

Comment: *"`cc` is instance of private type `C`"* No, `cc` is instance of nested class `X`. --- *"`bb` is instance of public type `B`"* No, `bb` is instance of nested class `Y`. --- Nowhere are you overriding the public method `hashCode()` inherited from class `Object`, so why do you think you shouldn't be able to call it?

Comment: But even if `C` _were_ private, `hashCode()` is a `public` member of `C`'s ultimate super-class, `Object`, which is `public`.  Only members declared by `C` itself would be inaccessible

Comment: And what does class `A` look like?

Comment: Guys, keep calm - I edited.

Comment: You need to (re)read the chapter in your Java guide on **inheritance** and method overriding.

Comment: Keep calm? We are calm. Are you complaining that we being reading your question too fast? If so, don't post it until you are ready. The original question was so riddled with nonsense statements, that we couldn't decipher what you were trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain it ? What does it mean in human-language?

Explanation:

1. The Java Puzzlers book is probably referring to something else.  (But who knows: you haven't given us the context.)
2. The Java Puzzlers book is not designed to be a specification, textbook or tutorial for the Java language.  We should therefore not try to use it as such ... and we should not treat its explanations as either complete or definitive.
3. In fact *you can* call methods of a non-public class if they implement or override methods declared in a public superclass or interface of the non-public class.

The technical explanation is that

```
A cc = c.foo();
```

is accessing a `foo()` method that is declared in `A` ... which is a `public` class.  The fact that `foo()` is overridden in a non-public class does not make the overriding method non-accessible.  And if it did, that would violate the principle of substitutability which is principle that makes polymorphism<sup>1</sup> work.

Or to put it more simply.

1. `c` is an instance of `A`.
2. Every `A` has a `foo()` method.
3. Anything to which the declaration of `A::foo()` is visible must be able to see the method on any instance of `A`.
4. If it can see it, it can invoke it.

---

<sup>1 - Strictly speaking, we are talking about subtype polymorphism here.  There are other kinds of polymorphism as  well to which LSP does not apply.</sup>